# Is git appropriate for users other than developers? Also file explorer interface for Git?

Tags: git

I've been using Git for source control of code written for Windows.  I use GitHub as the repository and I use the nice Windows app as front end.  I have not needed to go to use the command line interface.

I have suggested to colleagues other than developers such as business analysts and software architects that they also use Git to help them track their documents but is this correct?

So is Git appropriate for documents other than code but related to software development?  Is there a better option.  Would just saving to a cloud based drive be enough?

Other colleagues would prefer closer integration with Windows file explorer so they perhaps want to right-click on a file and do some operation (checkout etc.)  instead of using Git App for Windows.  Is this possible? wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is mostly made for managing source code.

Nothing prevents it from managing binary files, but it's not that good at it.

It won't able to merge modifications, and it will version the full file every time, resulting a very big repository size.

Most "cloud drive" solutions allow you to see previous version of a document, like google drive or dropbox.

---

Also, for managing git repository from windows explorer, you might want to see about Tortoise git.

Still, some basic concepts one must understand when using git are too abstract for a non-developper to fully understand.

Comment: Thanks for answering both parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but it's not really great. Those document are probably binary files. Storing those in git is much less efficient, and you won't benefit from the ability to search and merge.

Especially merging is an issue for binaries (bluntly said, it's not possible), and it would be better to have a centralised version control system like SVN that supports [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control#File_locking) when working with binaries.

So I'd go for a VCS that supports locking, or choose a cloud service that supports versioning of documents.